# Why is my PHP code to copy a folder to another folder on box.com not working?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using php curl to copy a folder to another folder (to become a subfolder inside the second folder).  Here is the curl option array (CODE value hidden) followed by the curl operations:

```
array (
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT     => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      =>
        array (
                'Authorization: Bearer CODE',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: '.$len,
              ),

    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => {"name":"Newfolder","parent":{"id":"$id"}}
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The result is '1'.

Comment: Actually, I had double quotes around the actual id but accidentally removed them when I substituted the id with $id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
```

Quoting from PHP Manual

> true to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.